# Restrict Firebase Realtime Database data request limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

In Firebase Realtime Database I want to set limit for number of data read request per user or per IP.
Similar like Firebase Authentication Limits(e.g New account creation 100 accounts/IP address/hour)

Is there any way to achieve this in Firebase Realtime Database ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to implement this would be to force client apps through a backend API that you control.  That API will have to record the amount of data read per IP, and reject requests that exceed your limits.

Otherwise, there is no way to impose limits as you describe.  It's not a matter of simple configuration.

Comment: No support for rate limits is truly crazy. I would suggest you mark it as a major security bug in Firebase so this can be taken care of.

Comment: You can file a feature request with Firebase support. It's not a security issue - it's a billing issue.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Is that mean anyone will able to hack Firebase app to explode your reads and potentially make you go bankrupt ? That must be a security issue.

Comment: Is it possible to control it using Google Cloud Platform ?

Comment: Billing limits is a common problem for all public cloud services.  You can set up a budget alert https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets if you want to know if there is a problem.